# How to Install Private Python Package in Docker image build

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

my goal is to dockerize python 3.6 web application.
During my work I developed private python package ('VmwareProviderBL') that my web application is using.

Build my docker image working perfectly, but when I am trying to run it, I get an error saying my private Python package is not found.

My Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run WebController.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "WebApi/WebController.py"]
```

My Error when trying to run the image

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WebApi/WebController.py", line 3, in <module>
    from VmwareProviderBL import SnapshotBL, MachineBL, Utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VmwareProviderBL'
```

My package hierarchy

```
--VmwareVirtualMachineProvider
  --WebApi
  --VmwareProviderBL
  --requirements
  --Dockerfile
```

Any ideas anyone?
I know I need somehow to add this package to my Dockerfile, did not find any example online.

Comment: I might have some idea on what might be going wrong. in your `Dockerfile` change the last line with these two lines and then try: `WORKDIR WebApi` and then `CMD ["python", "WebController.py"]`

Comment: @Arpit Goyal The same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `import` a module, Python looks in (a) the built-in path (`sys.path`), (b) locations in the `PYTHONPATH` variable, and (c) in the directory containing the script you're running.

You're installing the *requirements* for your module (`pip install -r requirements.txt`), but you're never installing the `VmwareProviderBL` module itself.  This means it's not going to be available in (a) above. The script you're running (`WebApi/WebController.py`) isn't located in the same directory as the `VmwareProviderBL` module, so that rules out (c).

The best way of solving this problem would be to include a `setup.py` file in your project so that you could simply `pip install .` to install both the requirements and the module itself.

You could also modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the directory that contains the `VmwareProviderBL` module. For example, add to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
```